# Intercept all REST API request made from local machine

Tags: wireshark, interceptor

I have a large JAVA application which connects to hundreds of cloud based systems using their REST API's and fetch the data from those systems.
To connects those different cloud systems we have different modules and each one have different approach to call REST API's like some modules using apache rest client some module using googles rest client.
So there is no centralise place where the REST api is getting called.

I have to track performance of the application e.g. to fetch accounts info from test system takes 1 hour. and this process need

- 4 api calls for https://test/api/v2/accounts -- (this will return all account id's)
- 8000 api calls for https://test/api/v2/accounts/{accountId}. --- (this will return deaths of each account)

I need to track what is the time taken by each api to responds and based on that calculate time taken by application to process that data.

Important part here is deatiled api analysis and make graphical data if possible e.g.

- 4 api calls for https://test/api/v2/accounts --- taken 3 minutes
- 8000 api calls for https://test/api/v2/accounts/{accountId} -- taken
  48 minutes

I need any any pointer how can I achieve that something like intercept all rest api made to https://test/api/v2

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably already discovered, without some extra tweaking, wireshark just shows you the connections at the FQDN level: you can't see which individual endpoint is called (because TLS, by design, hides the content of the connection). You have a few options though:

- if you control the APIs that are being connected to, you can load the
  TLS keys into wireshark, and it'll let you [decrypt](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#tls-decryption) the TLS
  connection;
- if you can force your app to use a proxy, you can use a Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) proxy (like [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/using)) to intercept the traffic; or
- you can instrument your app to log destination and duration for all the API requests.

Comment: Wireshark shows me data for api's
but I want more controlled way like calculating total time taken bay similar api's
and present data in readable form
like


endpoint1---4 calls -- total 8 minutes -- avg time 2 minutes
endpoint2---8000 calls -- total 48 minutes -- avg time 12 seconds

Comment: If this is a one-off piece of analysis, then the proxy or wireshark approach should give you that. If this is something that would be repeated, then instrumenting your code would make more sense.